# Polymer core-list item tap event

Tags: javascript, cordova, polymer

Using Polymer for PhoneGap I would like to add a tap event for a core-list item to know which element from the list was tapped.

What I've tried:

```
<core-list id="list" name="list" attributes="" height="120" style="height:100%;" selectionEnabled="true" on-core-select="{{selectedHandler}}">
                <template>
                     <core-card id="core_card" layout vertical>
                         <div class="row {{ { selected: selected } | tokenList }}">
                             <div flex>
                                 <core-image style="width:100%; height:200px; border-top-left-radius: 7px;
                                     border-top-right-radius: 7px; background-color: lightgray;" src="{{model.event_image}}" sizing="cover" preload>
                                 </core-image>
                                 </br>
                                 <div style="text-transform: none;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px">{{model.event_title}}</div>
                                 <div style="text-transform: none;padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px">{{model.event_location}}</div>
                                 </br>
                                 <div style="height:1px;width:100%;background:#999"></div>
                                 <div style="text-transform: none;padding-left:10px;padding-top:8px;color:#999">READ MORE</div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                    </core-card>
                    <div style="height:10px"></div>
                </template>
                <script>
                    (function () {
                     Polymer({
                             is: "list",
                             selectedHandler: function(e, detail, sender) {
                                alert('aa');
                             }
                             });
                     })();
                    </script>
            </core-list>
```

But the alert dialog is not displayed when tapping an item from the list. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888111/tap-listener-for-polymer-iron-list-item

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I still can't make it work and that sample is not a core-list.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You don't use Polymer 1.x? I think `core-*` aren't compatible with Polymer 1.x or are they? AFAIK iron-list is the successor of core-list.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go is to observe this.$.list.selection in your component since it will be updated with the item selected.